# Annotate QuerySet with first value of ordered related model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-1.10

I have a `QuerySet` of some objects. For each one, I wish to annotate with the minimum value of a related model (joined on a few conditions, ordered by date). I can express my desired results neatly in SQL, but am curious how to translate to Django's ORM.

#### Background

Let's say that I have two related models: `Book`, and `BlogPost`, each with a foreign key to an `Author`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    date_published = models.DateField()

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    date_published = models.DateField()
```

I'm trying to find the first mystery book that a given author published after each blog post that they write. In SQL, this can be achieved nicely with windowing.

#### Working solution in PostgreSQL 9.6

```sql
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT blog_post.id,
         book.title,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY blog_post.id ORDER BY book.date_published
         ) AS rn
    FROM blog_post
         LEFT JOIN book ON book.author_id = blog_post.author_id
                       AND book.genre = 'mystery'
                       AND book.date_published >= blog_post.date_published
)
SELECT id,
       title
  FROM ordered
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

#### Translating to Django's ORM

While the above SQL suits my needs well (and I could use raw SQL if needed), I'm curious as to how one would do this in QuerySet. I have an existing QuerySet where I'd like to annotate it even further

```
books = models.Book.objects.filter(...).select_related(...).prefetch_related(...)
annotated_books = books.annotate(
    most_recent_title=...
)
```

I'm aware that Django 2.0 supports window functions, but I'm on Django 1.10 for now.

#### Attempted solution

I'd first built a `Q` object to filter down to mystery books published after the blog post.

```
published_after = Q(
    author__book__date_published__gte=F('date_published'),
    author__book__genre='mystery'
)
```

From here, I attempted to piece together `django.db.models.Min` and additional `F` objects to acheive my desired results, but with no success.

Note: Django 2.0 introduces window expressions, but I'm currently on Django 1.10, and curious how one would do this with the QuerySet features available there.

Comment: Honestly (and without being an expert at all), I don't *think* you can do this in a single query using Django's 1.10 ORM... Subqueries are introduced in Django 1.11 and (as you said) window expressions are introduced in 2.0 **:-(**

Comment: did you try `annotate(first=Min(<related_model__id>)).filter(<conditions with timestamps>)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps using `.raw` isn't such a bad idea. Checking the code for [`Window` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/expressions/#Window) we can see that essentially composes an SQL query to achieve the "Windowing".

An easy way out may be the usage of the [architect](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect) module which can add partition functionality for PostgreSQL according to [the documentation](http://architect.readthedocs.io/features/partition/postgresql.html).

Another module that claims to inject Window functionality to Django < 2.0 is the [django-query-builder](https://github.com/ambitioninc/django-query-builder/tree/master) which adds a [`partition_by()`](http://django-query-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_examples.html#aggregates) queryset method and can be used with `order_by`:

> ```
> query = Query().from_table(
>     Order,
>     ['*', RowNumberField(
>               'revenue', 
>               over=QueryWindow().order_by('margin')
>                                 .partition_by('account_id')
>           )
>     ]
> )
> query.get_sql()
> # SELECT tests_order.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY margin ASC) AS revenue_row_number
> # FROM tests_order
> ```

Finally, you can always copy the `Window` class source code in your project or use [this alternate](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26608) Window class code.

Answer (score 3):

Your apparent problem is that Django 1.10 is too old to handle [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) properly (which have been around for a *very* long time already).

That problem goes away if you rewrite your query without window function.

#### 3 equivalent queries

Which of them is fastest depends on available indexes and data distribution. But each of them should be faster than your original.

**1.** With **`DISTINCT ON`**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id)
       p.id, b.title
FROM   blog_post p
LEFT   JOIN book b ON b.author_id = p.author_id
                  AND b.genre = 'mystery'
                  AND b.date_published >= p.date_published
ORDER  BY p.id, b.date_published;
```

Related, with detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

**2.** With a **`LATERAL` subquery** (requires Postgres 9.3 or later):

```
SELECT p.id, b.title
FROM   blog_post p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT title
   FROM   book 
   WHERE  author_id = p.author_id
   AND    genre = 'mystery'
   AND    date_published >= p.date_published
   ORDER  BY date_published
   LIMIT  1
   ) b ON true;
-- ORDER BY p.id  -- optional
```

Related, with detailed explanation:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

**3.** Or simpler, yet, with a **correlated subquery**:

```
SELECT p.id
     ,(SELECT title
       FROM   book 
       WHERE  author_id = p.author_id
       AND    genre = 'mystery'
       AND    date_published >= p.date_published
       ORDER  BY date_published
       LIMIT  1)
FROM   blog_post p;
-- ORDER BY p.id  -- optional
```

Each should be translated easily to Django syntax. You might also just use the raw SQL, that's what is sent to the Postgres server anyway.